# Linkedln Update Enagagement API Endpoint

Tags: linkedin-api

I was trying to find the LinkedIn Update Engagement API Endpoint URL. I am looking for - **Update Title, Update Link, Update type, Posted By, Create Date, Audience, Impression, views, Click, click through rate, likes, comment, share, Follows, Engagement , Content type.**
Can any one please guide me on this?

Appreciate your guidance

Comment: Please post what effort you have put into finding this information yourself.

Comment: @mxmissile...I tried the below things    First i used an api key with the scope r_organization_social for https://api.linkedin.com/v2/sharesq=owners&owners=urn:li:organization:{organizationid} 

Then, use the ID's of that result in: https://api.linkedin.com/v2/organizationalEntityShareStatistics?q=organizationalEntity&organizationalEntity=urn:li:organization:{organizationID}&shares[0]=urn:li:share:id1&shares[1]=urn:li:share:id2 (For multiple ids)

Comment: @mxmissile..also I tried this endpoint also. GET https://api.linkedin.com/v2/organizationalEntityShareStatistics?q=share&organizationalEntity=urn:li:organization:2414183&timeIntervals.timeGranularityType=DAY&timeIntervals.timeRange.start=1551398400000&timeIntervals.timeRange.end=1552003200000 this endpoint is giving me invalid query parameter. I tried with LinkedIn protocol version 2.0.0 as well